# SharePoint 2013 Search Issue

Tags: content-type, site-column, enterprise-search

We have setup SharePoint 2013 on windows 2012 server. It is have cumulative update until August. Its version is 15.0.4535.1000.

I have created two site content type of document type. Both content type have 4 site column are common in them. Both have two site column separate in each. I configure search service application, which is also working very good and also don't have any kind of error. I have added this two content type in one document library which have lot of sub-folders

Now the issue is that when I search anything from search center, sometimes I will get result with data from site columns and sometime i will not get data but just link to file and Name of the file. Wired thing is that columns are common and they crawling Full and Incremental also properly.

So what can be the issue for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, are you using Content Approval? If so, can you try publishing a Major Version of the document and re-running the search?

If that doesn't work, did you try to re-index your search service and run a full crawl again?

Comment: I don't have issue with Version as I can see the files link into the search but I cannot see its metadata values. What I found is that Only file are different but all data for the record is same . For example there is three files and three columns which have same record in it. So may be SharePoint is thinking it as duplicate and not showing but for me I need to show them

Answer (score 0):

Try disable duplicate result removal with this script: http://techmikael.blogspot.de/2013/12/duplicate-trimming-in-sharepoint-2013.html?m=1

Its not clear from your text - do the files contain the same content and only the metadata change?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. My metadata are same and about file very few things are change like date some nominal text but almost all content of the file is same.   Here situation is I am getting link to the files in result but I am not getting metadata text with it as they are same.

Comment: That sounds like trimm duplicate removes the "similar" files. Try the script I linked.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try that in evening when I reach to the server.

Comment: Script what you gave is for Microsoft Online and Our SharePoint is in premises, So how can we do same thing our hosted SharePoint

Comment: Well I removed the Credential Part, script was executed successfully but it did not resolve my issue. But still I kept my Index server to do full crawl, lets see did it help or not. I will keep posting.

Comment: Nothing works for me. Still I am not getting any summary in search results.